# converting a hex string back to a string, in Java

Tags: java, string, methods, hex

I am struggling trying to convert a hex number string back to the original string. I convert the string using the following method:

```
 private static String hex(String  binStr) {

        String newStr = new String();

        try {
            String hexStr = "0123456789ABCDEF";
            byte [] p = binStr.getBytes();
            for(int k=0; k < p.length; k++ ){
                int j = ( p[k] >> 4 )&0xF;
                newStr = newStr + hexStr.charAt( j );
                j = p[k]&0xF;
                newStr = newStr + hexStr.charAt( j ) + " ";
            }   
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to convert into hex values: " + e);
        } 

        return newStr;
    }
```

I am really stuck, and any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you give sample input and the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```
     String hexStr = "0123456789ABCDEF";
     long i = Long.valueOf(hexStr, 16);
     System.out.println(Long.toHexString(i));
```

Answer (score 1):

The code in the question destroys information. Only the most significant two bits and the least significant four bits of each input byte contribute to the result. That means it cannot, in general, be reversed.

If the right shift had been by four bits, instead of 6:

```
int j = ( p[k] >> 4 )&0xF;
```

all the input would have been preserved, and the original string could have been recovered from the hex string. Maybe you really meant the four bit shift?

Comment: Yes sorry, I did indeed mean 4 bits; >> 4

Comment: Which version did you actually use to generate the string you are trying to convert back?